# Не работает функция загрузки только из первого окна (диалога)

Tags: python, pyqt5, разработка-игр, qpushbutton, qlayout

Не работает корректно кнопка загрузки, если использовать ее из первого окна.

Первая кнопка в главном окне - сохранение, 
вторая -- загрузка, 
третья -- создать новое поле.

Не работает функция загрузки только из первого окна (диалога), хотя сама функция вызывается в основном окне (**`gg`**) также как и его рабочий брат из основного окна, но вот он работает как надо.

```
import random, sys, pymorphy2, webbrowser
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QWidget, QInputDialog, QPushButton, QFileDialog, \
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QLabel, QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QRect


class Start(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.main = root
        self.resize(200, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Start menu')

        self.size_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.size_widget.setGeometry(QRect(30, 30, 351, 175))
        self.layout = QFormLayout(self.size_widget)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.new_label = QLabel('Новая игра', self)
        self.load_label = QLabel('Загрузить поле', self)

        self.new_button = QPushButton(self)
        self.new_button.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.new_button.clicked.connect(self.new_clicked)
        self.new_button.setIcon(QIcon('new_im.png'))
        self.new_button.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))

        self.load_btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.load_btn.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.load_btn.clicked.connect(self.load_clicked)
        self.load_btn.setIcon(QIcon('load_im.png'))
        self.load_btn.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))

        self.layout.setWidget(0, QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.new_button)
        self.layout.setWidget(0, QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.new_label)
        self.layout.setWidget(1, QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.load_label)
        self.layout.setWidget(1, QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.load_btn)

    def new_clicked(self):
        self.main.start_arg = 'new'
        self.close()

    def load_clicked(self):
        self.main.start_arg = 'load'
        #fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file')
        #f = open(fname[0], 'r').read().split('], ')
        #self.main.matrix = []
        #for i in f:
        #    if i == f[-1]:
        #        i = i[1:-1].split(', ')
        #    else:
        #        i = i[1:].split(', ')
        #    lst = [int(j) for j in i]
        #    self.main.matrix.append(lst)
        #self.main.size = len(self.main.matrix[0])
        #self.main.load_fl = True
        self.close()


class gg(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.load_fl = False
        self.have_size = False
        self.field = False
        self.start_arg = 'new'
        Start(self).exec()
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Пятнашки')
        self.cell_size = 100
        if self.start_arg == 'load' and self.load_fl is False:
            self.load()
        elif self.have_size:
            self.matrix = []
            self.have_size = False
        elif self.load_fl is False:
            self.matrix = []
            self.new_field_dialog()

        self.empty = self.size * self.size
        if len(self.matrix) == 0:
            self.matrix_create()
        self.setFixedSize(self.cell_size * self.size + 62, self.cell_size * self.size)

        self.save_btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.save_btn.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.save_btn.setIcon(QIcon('save_im.png'))
        self.save_btn.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))
        self.save_btn.clicked.connect(self.save)

        self.load_btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.load_btn.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.load_btn.setIcon(QIcon('load_im.png'))
        self.load_btn.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))
        self.load_btn.clicked.connect(self.load)

        self.doc_btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.doc_btn.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.doc_btn.setIcon(QIcon('doc_im.png'))
        self.doc_btn.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))
        self.doc_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open('https://www.logozavr.ru/1640/'))

        self.new_btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.new_btn.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.new_btn.setIcon(QIcon('new_im.png'))
        self.new_btn.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))
        self.new_btn.clicked.connect(self.new_f)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(-1)
        vbox.setSpacing(0)
        vbox.addWidget(self.save_btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.load_btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.new_btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.doc_btn)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(0)
        hbox.addLayout(vbox)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

    def new_f(self):
        cancel = self.new_field_dialog()
        if cancel:
           self.have_size = True
           self.setupUI()

    def save(self):
        try:
            fileName = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save file')
            if fileName:
                f = open(fileName[0], 'w')
                f.write(str(self.matrix)[1:-1])
        except Exception:
            pass

    def load(self):
        try:
            fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file')
            f = open(fname[0], 'r').read().split('], ')
            self.matrix = []
            for i in f:
                if i == f[-1]:
                    i = i[1:-1].split(', ')
                else:
                    i = i[1:].split(', ')
                lst = [int(j) for j in i]
                self.matrix.append(lst)
            self.size = len(self.matrix[0])
            self.load_fl = True
            self.setupUI()
        except Exception:
            pass

    def matrix_create(self):
        self.n = 0
        cells_value = list(range(1, self.size * self.size))
        random.shuffle(cells_value)
        cells_value.append(self.empty)
        self.matrix = []
        for i in range(self.size):
            lst = []
            for j in range(self.size):
                lst.append(cells_value.pop(0))
            self.matrix.append(lst)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()
        y = pos.x() // self.cell_size
        x = pos.y() // self.cell_size
        def cell_find(x, y):
            try:
                if x < 0 or y < 0:
                    raise IndexError
                return self.matrix[x][y], x, y
            except IndexError:
                return None
        try:
            near_cells = [
                cell_find(x - 1, y),
                cell_find(x + 1, y),
                cell_find(x, y - 1),
                cell_find(x, y + 1)]
            empty_cell = []
            for i in near_cells:
                if i is not None and i[0] == self.empty:
                    empty_cell.append(i)
            if len(empty_cell) > 0:
                value = cell_find(x, y)[0]
                empty_value, x2, y2 = empty_cell[0]
                self.matrix[x][y] = empty_value
                self.matrix[x2][y2] = value
                lst = []
                for row in self.matrix:
                    for j in row:
                        lst.append(j)
                lst.pop()
                self.n += 1
                word = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer().parse('ход')[0]
                w = word.make_agree_with_number(self.n).word
                if lst == list(range(1, self.size * self.size)):
                    vict_massage = QMessageBox(self)
                    vict_massage.information(self, 'Victory', 'Ура, вы сделали это,' + '\n'
                                                                                       'на это у вас ушло ' + str(
                        self.n) + ' ' + w + '!')
                    self.matrix_create()
            self.update()
        except IndexError:
            pass

    def new_field_dialog(self):
       try:
           in_d = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Ввод размера', 'Введи число от 3 до 10 (размер поля)')
           text, ok = in_d
           if ok:
               self.size = int(text)
               if self.size < 3 or self.size > 10:
                   raise ValueError
           elif self.field is False:
               exit()
           else:
               return False
           return True
       except ValueError:
           error_m = QMessageBox(self)
           error_m.information(self, 'error', 'Неверный ввод, попробуйте снова.')
           self.new_field_dialog()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.field = True
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QColor('black'))
        for i, row in enumerate(self.matrix):
            y = i * self.cell_size
            for j, value in enumerate(row):
                x = j * self.cell_size
                if value == self.empty:
                    qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor('white'))
                else:
                    qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor('green'))
                qp.drawRect(x, y, self.cell_size, self.cell_size)
                if value != self.empty:
                    text = str(value)
                else:
                    text = ''
                qp.drawText(x, y, self.cell_size, self.cell_size, Qt.AlignCenter, text)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = gg()
ex.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: объясните пожалуйста, что у вас происходит в методе `def load(self):` ? Что вы хотите там сделать?

Comment: Он из выбранного файла достает строку(строки) и использует ее как матрицу для поля в игре.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я отметил для вас строки, в которые внес изменения и переставил местами. Уберите текст, который я добавил на кнопки для отладки. Пробуйте:

```
import sys
import random
import pymorphy2                                             # pip install pymorphy2
import webbrowser
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QWidget, QInputDialog, \
    QPushButton, QFileDialog, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QLabel, QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QRect


class Start(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, root=None): 
#        super().__init__(root)
        super(Start, self).__init__() 
        
        self.main = root
        self.resize(200, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Start menu')

        self.size_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.size_widget.setGeometry(QRect(30, 30, 351, 175))
#        self.layout = QFormLayout(self.size_widget)
#        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.new_label = QLabel('Новая игра', self)
        self.load_label = QLabel('Загрузить поле', self)

        self.new_button = QPushButton('Start\nnew', self)
        self.new_button.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.new_button.clicked.connect(self.new_clicked)
        self.new_button.setIcon(QIcon('new_im.png'))
        self.new_button.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))

        self.load_btn = QPushButton('Start\nload', self)
        self.load_btn.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.load_btn.clicked.connect(self.load_clicked)
        self.load_btn.setIcon(QIcon('load_im.png'))
        self.load_btn.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))

        self.layout = QFormLayout(self.size_widget)                          # +
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)                           # +
        self.layout.setWidget(0, QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.new_button)
        self.layout.setWidget(0, QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.new_label)
        self.layout.setWidget(1, QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.load_label)
        self.layout.setWidget(1, QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.load_btn)

    def new_clicked(self):
        self.main.start_arg = 'new' 
        self.close()

    def load_clicked(self):
        self.main.start_arg = 'load'           
        self.close()

# была ошибка !
# QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on gg "", which already has a layout
class Game(QWidget):                                           # - gg, + Game
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.load_fl = False
        self.have_size = False
        self.field = False
        self.start_arg = 'new'
        self.n = 0                                                      # +++
        
        start_arg = Start(self)
        start_arg.exec_()
        
        self.setupUI()
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.save_btn = QPushButton("save", self)                       # save
        self.save_btn.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.save_btn.setIcon(QIcon('save_im.png'))
        self.save_btn.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))
        self.save_btn.clicked.connect(self.save)

        self.load_btn = QPushButton("load", self)                       # load
        self.load_btn.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.load_btn.setIcon(QIcon('load_im.png'))
        self.load_btn.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))
        self.load_btn.clicked.connect(self.load)

        self.doc_btn = QPushButton("doc", self)                         # doc
        self.doc_btn.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.doc_btn.setIcon(QIcon('doc_im.png'))
        self.doc_btn.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))
        self.doc_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open('https://www.logozavr.ru/1640/'))

        self.new_btn = QPushButton('new', self)                         # 'new'
        self.new_btn.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        self.new_btn.setIcon(QIcon('new_im.png'))
        self.new_btn.setIconSize(QSize(40, 40))
        self.new_btn.clicked.connect(self.new_f)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(-1)
        vbox.setSpacing(0)
        vbox.addWidget(self.save_btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.load_btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.new_btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.doc_btn)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)                  
        self.hbox.addStretch(0)
        self.hbox.addLayout(vbox)        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

    def setupUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Пятнашки')
        self.cell_size = 100
        if self.start_arg == 'load' and self.load_fl is False:
            self.load()
        elif self.have_size:
            self.matrix = []
            self.have_size = False
        elif self.load_fl is False:
            self.matrix = []
            self.new_field_dialog()
            
### TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
        self.empty = self._size * self._size           # +++ замените `size` на `_size` ВЕЗДЕ!!!
        
        if len(self.matrix) == 0:
            self.matrix_create()
        self.setFixedSize(self.cell_size * self._size + 62, self.cell_size * self._size)

        ''' перенес в конструктор !!!
        self.save_btn = QPushButton("save", self)  # save
        ...
        self.hbox.addLayout(vbox)
        '''
        
    def new_f(self):
        cancel = self.new_field_dialog()
        if cancel:
           self.have_size = True
           self.setupUI()

    def save(self):
        try:
            fileName = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save file')
            if fileName:
                f = open(fileName[0], 'w')
                f.write(str(self.matrix)[1:-1])
        except Exception:
            pass

    def load(self):
        try:
            fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file')
            f = open(fname[0], 'r').read().split('], ')              # ???
            self.matrix = []
            for i in f:
                if i == f[-1]:
                    i = i[1:-1].split(', ')
                else:
                    i = i[1:].split(', ')
                lst = [int(j) for j in i]
                self.matrix.append(lst)
            self._size = len(self.matrix[0])
            self.load_fl = True
            self.setupUI()
        except Exception:
            pass

    def matrix_create(self):
        self.n = 0
        cells_value = list(range(1, self._size * self._size))
        random.shuffle(cells_value)
        cells_value.append(self.empty)
        self.matrix = []
        for i in range(self._size):
            lst = []
            for j in range(self._size):
                lst.append(cells_value.pop(0))
            self.matrix.append(lst)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()
        y = pos.x() // self.cell_size
        x = pos.y() // self.cell_size
        def cell_find(x, y):
            try:
                if x < 0 or y < 0:
                    raise IndexError
                return self.matrix[x][y], x, y
            except IndexError:
                return None
        try:
            near_cells = [
                cell_find(x - 1, y),
                cell_find(x + 1, y),
                cell_find(x, y - 1),
                cell_find(x, y + 1)]
            empty_cell = []
            for i in near_cells:
                if i is not None and i[0] == self.empty:
                    empty_cell.append(i)
            if len(empty_cell) > 0:
                value = cell_find(x, y)[0]
                empty_value, x2, y2 = empty_cell[0]
                self.matrix[x][y] = empty_value
                self.matrix[x2][y2] = value
                lst = []
                for row in self.matrix:
                    for j in row:
                        lst.append(j)
                lst.pop()
                self.n += 1
                word = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer().parse('ход')[0]
                w = word.make_agree_with_number(self.n).word
                if lst == list(range(1, self._size * self._size)):
                    vict_massage = QMessageBox(self)
                    vict_massage.information(self, 'Victory', 'Ура, вы сделали это,' + '\n'
                                                                                       'на это у вас ушло ' + str(
                        self.n) + ' ' + w + '!')
                    self.matrix_create()                   
            self.update()
        except IndexError:
            pass

    def new_field_dialog(self):
       try:
           in_d = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Ввод размера', 'Введи число от 3 до 10 (размер поля)')
           text, ok = in_d
           if ok:
               self._size = int(text)
               if self._size < 3 or self._size > 10:
                   raise ValueError
           elif self.field is False:
               exit()
           else:
               return False
           return True
       except ValueError:
           error_m = QMessageBox(self)
           error_m.information(self, 'error', 'Неверный ввод, попробуйте снова.')
           self.new_field_dialog()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.field = True
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QColor('black'))
        for i, row in enumerate(self.matrix):
            y = i * self.cell_size
            for j, value in enumerate(row):
                x = j * self.cell_size
                if value == self.empty:
                    qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor('white'))
                else:
                    qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor('green'))
                qp.drawRect(x, y, self.cell_size, self.cell_size)
                if value != self.empty:
                    text = str(value)
                else:
                    text = ''
                qp.drawText(x, y, self.cell_size, self.cell_size, Qt.AlignCenter, text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Game()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @Cilc пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Мне тяжело понять логику вашей программы, но я вам покажу один из вариантов игры "Пятнашки"

```
import sys
from random import randint 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPropertyAnimation, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class Game15(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self, None, Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        
        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(15):                                   
            self.buttons.append(exec(f'self._{i+1} = ...'))
            self.buttons[i] = QPushButton(self)
            self.buttons[i].clicked.connect(self._clicked)
            self.buttons[i].setText(str(i + 1))
       
        self.poss, self.font = [], QFont() 
        self.steps, self.msg_win = QLabel('st. : 0', self), QMessageBox()

        self.reload_btn = QPushButton('reload', self)
        self.reload_btn.clicked.connect(self.reload) 
        self.MV = ...

        self.mv(self, 0, 0, 'win')
        self.set_ui()
        self.reload()                                       
        
    def set_ui(self):
        self.resize(280, 400)
        self.steps.setGeometry(0, 370, 60, 30)
        self.font.setBold(1)
        self.font.setPointSize(12)
        self.reload_btn.setGeometry(180, 370, 100, 30)
        self.msg_win.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.msg_win.setFont(self.font)
        self.msg_win.setText('win')
        
        _x, _y = 0, 0
        for i in self.buttons:
            i.setFont(self.font)
            i.setGeometry(_x, _y, 70, 70)
            self.poss.append([_x, _y])
            _x, _y = (lambda a, b: (a+70, b) if a <= 140 else (0, b+70))(_x, _y)     
        
    def _clicked(self):
        for btn in self.buttons:
            if btn.hasFocus():
                k, l, c = self.ch_m(btn)
                if k:
                    self.steps.setText('st. : {}'.format(
                        int(self.steps.text()[self.steps.text().find(':') + 1:]) + 1 )
                    )
                    self.mv(btn, l, c)                      

    def ch_m(self, obj:QPushButton):
        if len([x.x() for x in self.buttons if x.y() == obj.y()]) < 4:
            for i in [0, 70, 140, 210]:
                if i not in [x.x() for x in self.buttons if x.y() == obj.y()] and \
                            obj.x() in [i+70, i-70]:
                    return [True, i, obj.y()]
        elif len([x.y() for x in self.buttons if x.x() == obj.x()]) < 4:
            for i in [0, 70, 140, 210]:
                if i not in [x.y() for x in self.buttons if x.x() == obj.x()] and \
                            obj.y() in [i+70, i-70]:
                    return [True, obj.x(), i]
        return [False, 0, 0]
        
    def mv(self, obj: QPushButton, a, b, ty='btn'):
        if ty == 'btn':
            self.MV_obj = QPropertyAnimation(obj, b'geometry')
            self.MV_obj.setDuration(100)
            self.MV_obj.setStartValue(QRect(obj.x(), obj.y(), obj.width(), obj.height()))
            self.MV_obj.setEndValue(QRect(a, b, obj.width(), obj.height()))
            self.MV_obj.finished.connect(self.check)
            self.MV_obj.start()
        elif ty == 'win':
            self.MV_obj = QPropertyAnimation(obj, b'windowOpacity')
            self.MV_obj.setDuration(2000)
            self.MV_obj.setStartValue(0)
            self.MV_obj.setEndValue(10)
            self.MV_obj.start()
            obj.show()
            
    def reload(self):
        s_l: list = self.poss.copy()
        for i in self.buttons:
            r = randint(0, len(s_l) - 1)        
            p = s_l.pop(r)
            i.setGeometry(p[0], p[1], 70, 70)
    
    def check(self):
        if [[a.x(), a.y()] for a in self.buttons] == self.poss:
            self.msg_win.setText('win\n\n steps: {}'.format(
                int(self.steps.text()[self.steps.text().find(':') + 1:]))
            )

            self.mv(self.msg_win, 0, 0, 'win')
            self.msg_win.finished.connect(self.reload)
            self.steps.setText('st. : 0')
          

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Game15()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: За пример конечно спасибо, но хотелось бы все таки понять почему так не логично откзазывается работать корректно код, когда мы вызываем self.load(), хотя когда эта же функция вызывается из-за нажатия кнопки кож работает гладко. А с пониманием кода я могу помочь)

Comment: @Cilc хорошо, гляну еще раз, чуть позже.